# JavaScript keeping array in order

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to keep an array in a particular order, and I've learned about the splice function to insert in a specific index location, but it doesn't seem to do the right thing.

Here's a fiddle of what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/drumichael/7r2pV/277/

In section 1, you can select one or many of the options, however "First" should always be 1st, "second" 2nd, and "Fourth" after both of those. If you only choose "First" & "Fourth", they should be in that order regardless of the order in which you checked the boxes.

In section 2 - you may only choose ONE of Options A, B, & C... and that option should always be in the 3rd position of the array (unless you didn't choose ANY items from Section 1 of course, it would be all by itself inside the array).

Honestly I'm not sure where to go from here. I've tried this:

```
var array_position = $(this).attr('id');
var messagePart = $(this).attr('data-message');

message.splice(array_position, 0, messagePart);
```

But they still dont end up in the proper order.

Comment: `message[array_position]=messagePart;` to insert in the right slot, which makes empty slots... then before you join(): `message.filter(Boolean).join(", ")` to remove the empty slots. you don't even need to mess with splice()...

Comment: If you choose all three options in Section 1, wouldn't the option in section 2 be in the fourth position? Did you mean Section 2 option is always last? Ok I see, Section 2 is the missing third position of Section 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the id's are numbered in the order you want, you can sort `$('.mycheckbox:checked')` by id. Then use the `$.each` function.

```
$(".mycheckbox").on("change", function() {
  var message = [];
  $('.mycheckbox:checked').sort(function(a, b) {
    return parseInt(a.id) > parseInt(b.id);
  }).each(function() {
    var messagePart = $(this).attr('data-message');
    message.push(messagePart);
  });
  $(".summary").html(message.join(", "));
});
```

**DEMO:**
http://jsfiddle.net/kom7hd5o/

**Resource:**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: Thanks! This did it!  I just gave the ID of 'first' 1, 'second' 2, 'fourth' 100, and the different options in section two a value somewhere in between!

Answer (score 0):

When using `splice()` the index the item is inserted to should be `0`-indexed. For example:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,5,6];
arr.splice(3, 0, 4);
```

will insert `4` into the 3rd `0`-indexed location.

Also, you need to use `0` as the 2nd parameter in `splice` when inserting a value like you want.

To make your code work you should change the `id` parameter of each input to be `0`-indexed, and then use `splice()` to insert the item.

```
$(".mycheckbox").on("change", function() {
  var message = [];
  $('.mycheckbox:checked').each(function() {
    var messagePart = $(this).attr('data-message');
    message.splice($(this).attr('id'), 0,messagePart);
  });
  $(".summary").html(message.join(", "));
});
```

Here's a working example:

```js
$(".mycheckbox").on("change", function() {
  var message = [];
  $('.mycheckbox:checked').each(function() {
    var messagePart = $(this).attr('data-message');
    message.splice($(this).attr('id'), 0,messagePart);
  });
  $(".summary").html(message.join(", "));
});


$("input:checkbox").on('click', function() {
  // in the handler, 'this' refers to the box clicked on
  var $box = $(this);
  if ($box.is(":checked")) {
    // the name of the box is retrieved using the .attr() method
    // as it is assumed and expected to be immutable
    var group = "input:checkbox[name='" + $box.attr("name") + "']";
    // the checked state of the group/box on the other hand will change
    // and the current value is retrieved using .prop() method
    $(group).prop("checked", false);
    $box.prop("checked", true);
  } else {
    $box.prop("checked", false);
  }
});
```

```css
.selection_area {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="selection_area">
  <h4>Select as many of these options as desired</h4>
  <p>Should appear in numerical order</p>
  <input type="checkbox" class="mycheckbox" id="1" data-message="Second" />Second
  <br/>
  <input type="checkbox" class="mycheckbox" id="0" data-message="First" />First
  <br/>
  <input type="checkbox" class="mycheckbox" id="3" data-message="Fourth" />Fourth
  <br/>
</div>

<h5>Summary of Selections:</h5>
<div class="summary"></div>
```

Here's an [updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/n0sw0ujo/1/).

Comment: Thanks! What about the options in Section 2? I tried using "data-order" instead of ID (since I cant assign all items in that section the same ID), however they don't always go in order.  I clicked several times and sometimes it ended up in order, sometimes it didn't.

Comment: Do you mean 3rd as in last position?

Comment: No, as in "In between Second and Fourth".  It has to be injected between those two selections from Section 1

Comment: Add `id="2"` to those checkboxes.